# Cannot close curly brackets on Android Studio with a AZERTY keyboard

Tags: android-studio, azerty-keyboard

Since yesterday, I cannot close curly brackets on Android Studio with my keyboard... I have an AZERTY french keyboard, and the closing curly bracket is optained by doing "alt gr" + "=".

- All the other char involving "alt gr" key are working on Android Studio (including opening curly brackets)
- I can insert closing curly brackets by "copy/pasting" this char in Android Studio
- This problem occures ONLY in Android Studio (here for instance, it is working: }})
- I already restart both Android Studio and my computer, but that does not solve the problem

Do you guys had some problem similar? Is it a temporary bug of Android Studio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `Shift` + `Alt gr` + `]`

Comment: Shift + Alt gr + ] is not doing anything

Comment: On my machine, it prints `}`. Possibly, it depends on the keyboard layout, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably with the software maybe there's is a setting which you might have accidentally messed up while snooping around. Was it working earlier?\

*edit:*

Add this line:

```
actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true
```

to this file:

```
...\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties
```

As written here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91975

Comment: Try using AltGr + Q

Comment: The fix is for Atom, no ? Not for Android Studio ?

Comment: NB: The file is a pain to edit. How I did on Windows:
- Open a cmd window as administrator
- Open the directory Program Files/Android/Android Studio/bin
- command notepad idea.properties
- Edit and save the file adding the magic line "...\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties"

Comment: Faster way to edit the file is clicking on "Help > Edit Custom Properties"